# Can I replace a junction box with a piece of conduit if I rewire the circuit completely?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a bathroom where the fixture was moved. Can I remove an old junction box if I use conduit joiners to splice in a piece of conduit ? I plan on rewiring the  fixture from the switch after.

Comment: If you are removing all the old wires and pulling new wires through, of appropriate gauge, it ought to be OK.

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron, what you propose is fine.

Remember, splices inside conduit are not allowed, so your plan to remove the j-box, extend the conduit, and pull new wire is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Wires that run through conduit must be complete and unbroken. So if you have to splice the wires together with wire nuts or whatever is appropriate for your jurisdiction, then no, you can just just join the conduit together.

Some other options:

- Cover the junction box with a blank cover and paint it to match your ceiling.
- Get an in-wall rated splice. http://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-Romex-Splice-Kit-2-Wire-1-Clam-CPGI-1116377-2/202204326
- Pull new cable beginning to end and use the junction.

Comment: He says he plans on removing the j-box, extending the conduit, and pulling new wire. There is no mention of splicing wire and cable.

Comment: True, but this is an important enough fact that it is worth stating anyway.